# Find index for all locations of a character with NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring

Programmatically I can see how many times a character exists in any given string:

```
    letterOccurences= [[tempWordStr componentsSeparatedByString:chosenCharacter] count];
```

So for the word Mississippi, if the chosen character was 'i' this function would return 4.

But what I would like to know is **where** the character appears in the string.  In the Mississippi case, this would be at 1,4,7,10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `NSString` method`rangeOfString:options:range:` - this finds and returns the range of a given string (ie, `@"i"`) within a given range. You simply need to adjust the given range of the receiver until you find no more instances of the substring.

Comment: I have been using this but an still hitting problems.  Any snippets?  Say for example we had the words GONE and GGOG, I want to print out G---- and GG-G.

Answer (score 1):

Using your trick of splitting the string, instead of just getting the count of elements in the returned array, get the length of each element in the array.  Loop and accumulate the lengths and add 1 for the missing "i".